# Main in MFC console app (NOT WinMain, main)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, mfc, console

For a sample program, though this is doing all good for me. But I was wondering how is it happening.

I created a console application with "MFC" checkbox enabled while creating the project (VC2008).
It created standard `_tmain` implementaion with `AfxWinInit` calls and all. Then I wrote my custom function **`Main`** and called it from `_tmain` itself.

Now as soon as press F10 or F11 to START debugging, it goes into `Main` and not `_tmain` (yes, via `_tmain` itself) - How and Why - that's the question.

No I didn't set any project setting at all. this is about 32-bit Debug build.

EDIT: The interesting thing is this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

void Main()
{
    printf("This is custom main");
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    if(false) // Getting fooled, or fooling us?
        Main();

    return 0;
}
```

Visual Studio considers `Main` as entry point, and doesn't do anything when I start debugging with F10/F11 - since `false` is false and doesn't allow `Main` to be called!

Comment: Please post your sample code.

Comment: Unable to instantly post the code right now. See comments for next post.

Comment: Where did you place `Main` in `_tmain` ?

Comment: I have NOT set any breakpoints - I just hit F11 or F10 to start debugging, which should start from entry-point. VS is considering custom `Main` to be entry point.

Comment: Does your `Main` contain a lot of code? Otherwise it might get inlined and end up being the first part of `_main`.

Comment: @Bo Persson: It's DEBUG mode. And as the ASM shows, it's not inline.

Comment: No, around 10-12 lines of code. And this is Debug build, so optimization may not play its role.

Comment: @Stan - What asm? I haven't seen any real code. And are we sure it is `Main` and not `main` by mistake?

Comment: Code is not important. Even if I place `void Main(){ }`, OR set of printfs, OR set of Windows API calls, it logically begins at `Main`

Comment: @Bo Persson: You can try a simple example on your computer. It acts like what Ajay have said. I'm sure it's `Main`. I tests it in VS2010. In all, it's up to the behavior of the debugger and it's interesting.

Comment: @Ajay: well, you mislead buddies here. The program begins at `_tmain`, just the debugger stops at `Main` :-)

Comment: I haven't misled anybody. Read the third paragraph of my unmodified question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My test shows it goes to `_tmain` first, before custom `Main`.

[image]

Comment: The signature is: `void Main()`. The call is just 'Main'. 
I haven't placed any breakpoint.

Comment: If you doesn't place any breakpoint, how do you confirm that the entry point is not _tmain?

Comment: @Yan Cheng CHEOK: Ajay knew the entry point is _tmain, he wondered why the debugger stoped at `Main` but not `_tmain`. It seems that not just me misunderstood Ajay's meaning.

Comment: I am NOT saying entry point is NOT _tmain. I mentioned VS starts debugging from custom `Main` as soon as I hit F10/F11. The call stack shows `_tmain` calling `Main`. No breakpoints, no inlining.